# Single-line TextView cuts text being inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a problem that I can't solve on my own.
I was trying to find the solution during last two days, Googling, reading answers on this site, playing with code, but failed...

I am making an overlay popup window that my Service will display obove any open application (like the Facebook ChatHead). Everything works except one thing:
*I've just registered so I don't have enough reputation to attach images, here is [the link to the screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101343196/device-2015-03-18-223539.png).*
The rightmost TextView (shown with a red arrow) is shrinked and we see only "R" instead of "RND".

Here is the RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llIcons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconRDS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="RDS"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconAS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="AS"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconTP"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="TP"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconREG"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="REG"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconCDin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="CD in"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconMP3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="MP3"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvIconRDM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="RDM"
            android:minEms="20"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/llIcons"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code that inflates this layout and adds it to the WindowManager:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
float displayDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int popupMargin = (int) (20 * displayDensity + 0.5f);
WindowManager.LayoutParams popupParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
popupParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
popupParams.y = popupMargin;
rlPopup = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.overflow_popup, null);
rlPopup.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.overflow_popup_shape);
windowManager.addView(rlPopup, popupParams);
```

I've already tryed the following:

- Using `android:layout_marginLeft` (`android:layout_marginRight`) instead of `android:paddingLeft` (`android:paddingRight`)
- Setting `minWidth`, `minEms` attributes for all Icons TextViews
- Setting `layout_width` attribute of all Icons TextViews to a fixed dp value instead of `wrap_contents`
- Setting `layout_width` attribute of llIcons LinearLayout to a fixed 1000dp value instead of `wrap_contents`
- Changing LinearLayout to RelativeLayout (with respective changes to the child elements)

Nothing helps, I still see "R" instead of "RND". Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

P.S. I can't do one common TextView instead of 7 because I need to control their style separately.

### Update one

I don't have enough reputation to add more than two links, so I have put the screenshots into a [zip-file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101343196/screnshots.zip).
So, what I've done:

1. First I have done like @Lamorak has adviced and got the following XML as a result:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/llIcons"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="5pt"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconRDS"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="RDS"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconAS"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="AS"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconTP"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="TP"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconREG"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="REG"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconCDin"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="CD in"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconMP3"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="MP3"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tvIconRDM"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:maxLines="1"
           android:text="RDM"
           android:textSize="30sp"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvText"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/llIcons"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_margin="7dp"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:focusable="true"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
       android:scrollHorizontally="true"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textSize="50sp"/>
   ```

   I have got the result from screenshot "option1". As you can see, that padding between elements is too small and all TextViews are shrinked to 2 letters.
2. Next I've tryed to replace all `android:layout_width="0dp"` with `android:layout_width:"wrap_content"`.
   The result is on "option2" screenshot - text is not cut but there is no padding between elements at all.
3. After that I've added `android:paddingLeft="30dp"` to all TextViews except the first one (`tvIconRDS`). Also I've added `android:paddingRight="15dp"` to the `tvIconRDM` TextView. 
   The result ("option3" screenshot) is most close to the desired one, except no padding from the left of "RDS".
4. But when I am trying to add `android:paddingLeft="15dp"`, or `android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"`, to the `tvIconRDS` TextView, or even `android:paddingLeft="15dp"` to `llIcons` LinearLayout, I get the following result: "option4" screenshot.

So, the most fitting option is number 3, but how to create a left padding of 15dp for the first icon?

### Update two

It works now! Finally I have managed to do it using TableLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlIcons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconRDS"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/rds_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconAS"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/as_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconTP"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/tp_icon_on"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconREG"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/reg_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconCDin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/cdin_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconMP3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/mp3_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvIconRDM"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/rdm_icon"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEHUText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="7"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it is because you are using in every TexView `android:paddingLeft="30dp`? You should use instead `layout_weight` parameter, and set it to `android:layout_weight="1` to every TextView. You can look at this [tutorial](http://startofandroid.com/en/lessons/complete-list/208-lesson-7-layout-parameters-for-view-elements.html), there are several examples of using weight parameter.

Comment: I  am not really friend of layout weighting but in this case it might help. Set `width="0dp"`, remove `paddings` and `minEms` and add the `weight`. This will part the width of the `LinearLayout` equally between the `TextViews`.

Comment: Thanks @VadymVL and you for an advice!
I have edited my question (see text after "Update one" header), could you have a look at it please?

Comment: I've tried to do it, but the main problem is an extra large font size. Because of it, textViews is overlapping on each other. If you can use smaller font size, all elements will fit the screen. If not, on my opinion, number 3 is the best result.

Comment: But why does `layout_width="wrap_content" ` doesn't do it's job? I thought it should wrap content regardless of it's size...

Comment: I thought the same. But mybe other parameters like weight and padding are override it's functional.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to do it using TableLayout. See "Update two" in my question text.
[Here is the result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101343196/device-2015-03-19-230209.png).